# Open feature class in in_memory workspace ArcGIS Pro SDK

Tags: in-memory, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am aware that one can open a feature class in a geodatabase using the code below.

```
Geodatabase geodatabase = new Geodatabase(new DatabaseConnectionFile(new Uri("path\\to\\sde\\file\\sdefile.sde")))
FeatureClass table = geodatabase.OpenDataset<FeatureClass>("FeatureClassName");
```

But how can I open a file that's saved in memory such as "in_memory/testFile"?

I have combed Esri's resources to no avail.

Comment: The memory-based workspaces are discussed [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) and even show up in the [Geoprocessing ProConcepts in ArcGIS Pro SDK Github](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProConcepts-Geoprocessing#executing-geoprocessing-tools), but all the examples are either Python or writes using the SDK. I can't find an example using the SDK to read from it.

Comment: Also, if you can output the memory-based feature class as a feature layer on a map, you can grab the feature class from that layer. But adding something to the map to grab a by-definition temporary feature class leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: @Soulis I have resorted to utilizing that methodology of creating and then adding the memory layer to the map and grabbing it that way and I agree, it's extremely clumsy.

Comment: I asked [the same question on GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/message/893249-how-can-i-access-the-memory-based-workspace-via-the-sdk), but no answer yet. I'll add an answer if it ever gets answered there.